# Sonar Checkstyle import: Rule template can't be activated on a Quality profile

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle

I'm trying to create a new quality profile with existing checkstyle ruleset but get the error message:

> Rule template can't be activated on a Quality profile:
>   checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.naming.ConstantNameCheck

I use the simplest ruleset example from the [checkstyle officail site](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html):

```
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="JavadocPackage"/>
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="AvoidStarImport"/>
        <module name="ConstantName"/>
        <module name="EmptyBlock"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

Versions: Sonar 4.5.1 with Checkstyle plugin 2.1.1

What is wrong?

Comment: Seems to be a bug, Sonar version 4.3.3 with the same configuration works fine.

Comment: Did anyone solve this? I read the answer below but do not understand what to do. I'm on version 4.5.1

Comment: stuck with the same issue on sonar 4.5.1. Not able to export checkstyle and pmd rules from sonar 4.2

Answer (score 3):

Those Checkstyle rules (like "ConstantNameCheck") are defined with a multiple cardinality in the SonarQube Checkstyle plugin. This means that it should be possible to activate several "instances" of those rules with different values for its parameters.

In SonarQube 4.4+, it is no more possible to have multiple activations of those rules. They are considered as "[rule templates](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Rules#Rules-RuleTemplates)", which means that you must create custom rules (with explicit parameters) out of them in order to be able to activate them on quality profiles.

Everything is explained on the [Rules documentation page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Rules).

Comment: I too have this problem and I'm so new to SonarQube that I do not understand the template page you point too. Is it possible for you to provide an example just so I can get my head around the issue

Comment: Checkstyle team will investigate what is possible to do to ease imports - https://github.com/checkstyle/sonar-checkstyle/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

Look at this.

http://dist.sonarsource.com/reports/coverage/checkstyle.html

It works, when you change it with this parameters.
For example ConstantName in checkstyle xml-file is S00115.
May be this is the solution.

Example:

```
<module name="S00115"/> <!--ConstantName-->
<module name="S00117">  <!--LocalFinalVariableName-->
   <property name="format" value="^[a-z_][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
</module>
```