# 110 rule(s) changed, 44 rule(s) ignored in profile testCheckstyle - Java - Cannot activate Sonar rules

Tags: android, sonarqube, checkstyle, sonarqube-scan

I have been trying to activate checkstyle rules in Sonarqube and came across this issue. I was trying to bulk activate all the 154 checkstyle rules in my quality profile and only 110 rules could be activated. 44 rules were ignored.

Also i could not see the activate button in the rule details page. I can see only a Create button option to extend the existing profile and create a new one. Does this mean i have to create a custom rule extending these 44 rules to enable them in my profile?

Sonarqube: 6.2

Checkstyle: 3.6

[image: Rules ignored]
[image: Activate button missing]

Comment: To answer your question: yep.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Could you please provide an explanation why this is happening? Why should i duplicate these rules to create a custom one even if i am ok to go with default values ? Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this concerns only template rules.
Example with rule "Boolean Expression Complexity" (checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.metrics.BooleanExpressionComplexityCheck)
See [Sonar Checkstyle import: Rule template can't be activated on a Quality profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886105/sonar-checkstyle-import-rule-template-cant-be-activated-on-a-quality-profile) for more details.

there is no activation button for these rules,you can either create them with default properties or with your custom properties.

I would suggest activating them with the properties used by google.

refer this link:https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml